# Creating links that go to pages in clicking user's profile

Tags: support, profile-page, hyperlinks

Is there any way to create links to a part of the profile page, such as the [revisions list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/151987/brad-mace?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), so that it will take the user to that page in *their own* profile? Just wondering so I could make links more generally useful when someone asks where to find something.

Comment: You mean, unlike [http://...brad-mace?tab=activity&sort=revisions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/151987/brad-mace?tab=activity&sort=revisions) which takes the visitor to _your_ revisions page?

Comment: Yes. I thought it'd be nice if other people who are looking for the same thing could be taken to their own page rather than the page of whoever initially asked the question.

Comment: Don't think there is a way, would be nice to have something like `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/me?tab=activity&sort=all` working though. Just in case it's ever implemented - [test case](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/me?tab=activity&sort=all) (currently leading to Page Not Found of course)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [/users/current](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current) and this works even with the extra query parameters as used in [Shadow Wizards test case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143421/creating-links-that-go-to-pages-in-clicking-users-profile#comment407741_143421)

> [`/users/current?tab=activity&sort=all`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=all)

Do know there are a few places where you would expect `/current` to work as well but the reality is harsh. See [Inconsistent support for /current](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298748/inconsistent-support-for-current) for a list where it isn't support.