# Inconsistent support for /current

Tags: feature-request, bug, profile-page, current-user

One nice quality-of-life feature on Stack Exchange is the ability to direct users to their own network profile using [`/current`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187925/351462). However, there are a few places where support for `/current` doesn't seem to have been implemented.

#### Supports `/current`

- Inbox [`https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox`](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=inbox)
- Network Profile<sup>1</sup>: [`https://stackexchange.com/users/current`](https://stackexchange.com/users/current)
- User Profile<sup>1</sup>: [`https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current)
- Edit Profile: [`https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current)
- Site Preferences: [`https://askubuntu.com/users/preferences/current`](https://askubuntu.com/users/preferences/current)
- My Logins: [`https://english.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current`](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current)
- Hide Communities: [`https://superuser.com/users/hidecommunities/current`](https://superuser.com/users/hidecommunities/current)
- Tag Future Report: [`https://stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/current`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/current)
- Flag Summary: [`https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/current`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/current)
- Deleted Questions: [`https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-questions/current`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-questions/current)
- Deleted Answers: [`https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-answers/current`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-answers/current)
- [Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019/282094) (formerly Bookmarks):
  [`https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/saves/current/all`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/saves/current/all)

#### Uses different URL format

- Searching<sup>3</sup>: [`https://serverfault.com/search?q=user:me`](https://serverfault.com/search?q=user:me)

#### Does not support `/current`

- User Flair: [`https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/current/flair`](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/current/flair) (Use: /users/flair)
- Authorized Applications: [`https://security.stackexchange.com/users/apps/current`](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/apps/current)
- Network Reputation Leagues:  [`https://stackexchange.com/leagues/195/month/workplace/2017-07-01/current`](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/195/month/workplace/2017-07-01/current)
- Stack Exchange Data Explorer: [`https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/330763/find-all-my-unaccepted-question-network-wide?accountid=current`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/330763/find-all-my-unaccepted-question-network-wide?accountid=current)
- User Badges: [`https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/9/autobiographer?userid=current`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/9/autobiographer?userid=current) *used* to work but no longer does

---

#### Notes

<sub><sup>1</sup>[Tabs on user and network profile pages are also supported](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=accounts).</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup>Also works with "mine" but searching [`user:current`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:current) will have no effect on search results.</sub>

Comment: Fyi `https://stackexchange.com/filters/favorite-tags` will already redirect you to your own filters. The user ID isn't needed.

Comment: @animuson Thank you for the clarification. I had assumed the user ID was necessary, since the final resolved URL includes the ID.

Comment: As well, your Data Explorer example is not something that can ever be supported. Data Explorer runs on open source software and does not have access to the account system for the rest of the network, and accounts there are not in any way attached to the rest of your network profile. Looking up the account ID there is simply not possible and never will be.

Comment: I've removed the filtered questions link completely. **It actually does not take a UserId in the URL at all.** The Id it inserts into the URL is actually the Id of the filter it selects by default, *not* your UserId or AccountId. So it doesn't make sense for `current` to be used there at all. As mentioned before, just using the bare URL works fine for this case.

Comment: It also doesn't work for [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/current), or any of the [chat profile tabs](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=prefs)

Comment: I note, however, that *as this question is currently written*, it is not a [tag:feature-request]. As written, this is just calling attention to the fact that `/current` is inconsistently implemented and listing the URLs where it is and isn't supported. It doesn't actually ask for any feature change or explain what is actually wanted to be changed regarding any specific URLs.

Comment: @Makyen My original intent was to see more consistent support for `/current`. However, now that the three job pages are scheduled for removal, my most straightforward examples no longer apply, so I'm unsure where it leaves my post.

Comment: Stevoisiak, I'm not saying the question isn't useful (it is useful, IMO), or that more consistent use of `current` wouldn't be beneficial. For me, it's just not clear what, if any, action is wanted here, particularly with the bounty from @αλεχολυτ. As a list of where `/current` (or similar) is function, this question is helpful, IMO. But I couldn't say what action/change is desired which would get this to [tag:status-completed] as a [tag:feature-request] or [tag:bug], nor what action is really desired from bringing more attention to it with a bounty.