# Replace internal links with question title in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, internal-links

When posting questions or answers, internal links are automatically converted into question titles.

i.e. `https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298748/351462` → [Inconsistent support for /current](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298748/351462)

Can the same functionality be added for chat messages?

[image: Mark <question> as duplicate of <question>]

---

<sub>**Related**: *[Replace links with the current question title in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77394/351462)*</sub>

Comment: FYI Onebox will work for one link (if the message didn't have any other text) . For some sites like wikipedia, images and internal links (posts/ user profile, etc.)