# Is there a way to link users to their profile page?

Tags: support, profile-page, hyperlinks

Say I'm writing a post on meta, and I want to direct the reader to a specific section of their profile page. One thing one can do is to just link to the profile page of the OP who asked the question, say,

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/12345/jane-doe,

and this will work for OP ─ but any future readers will be redirected to Jane's profile page instead of their own. Is there a smart way to use the SE url handling (say, something along the lines of

https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/me

or something similar) which will send any logged-in user to their profile page? (And which, ideally, will carry along any additional attributes such as `?tab=badges` and the like?)

Comment: Apologies if this is a duplicate ─ it feels like it might be, but I couldn't find any previous instances. If there's a previous thread asking this that I couldn't find, I blame the not-super-useful SE search feature.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298748/inconsistent-support-for-current

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it exists; instead of `me`, use `current`. Example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current and it remembers query parameters, e.g. this link works too: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=badges

The only exception is the 'Edit profile & settings' page which has a slightly different syntax: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current

It works on the network profile too: https://stackexchange.com/users/current.