# Can we get a current user link for flairs?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, flair, current-user

My profile has a link to the flair page on it, so others can use them. However, it is a link to the flair page for *me*, because the `/current` trick (which replaces "current" with the logged-in user's ID) doesn't work.

**Can we have `https://%.stackexchange.com/users/current/x/flair` redirect to the logged-in user's version of the page?** This would be really nice; I could put it on my profile so people could have flairs, an obscure feature that I didn't understand for quite a while.

Comment: Why not, with a default dummy flair as the expected output for logged-out users, if doable.

Comment: We'd probably have to change the path to `/users/flair/{id}` (which is consistent with the actual image path that just appends ".png" to that) in order to get a "current" redirect there. Throwing it into the middle of a URL like that is just weird and doesn't match any other profile URLs we have.

Comment: related as that there are more inconsistencies that might need fixing in one go instead of a bit here and a bit there: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298748/inconsistent-support-for-current?rq=1